# Format culture issue in en-ZA .net

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, regex, culture

I have a small application, written on asp .net C#, which takes input from a user in a textbox, there are two buttons - on clicking the first one, i'll populate a second textbox with the culture specific value. I'm trying to set the input value to the culture en-ZA.

Here is my code in cs file,

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
{
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-ZA");
    //base.InitializeCulture();
}

protected void btnCulture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal val = Convert.ToDecimal(txtValue.Text, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    txtConverted.Text = val.ToString("0,0.00");
}
```

Now, on second button click, i've written a javascript function, which will read the value from the textbox and tries to match it with a regular expression.

A sample input is 12345 is parsed as 12 345.00 and one would hope the regular expression to be something like this --> ^[+-]?[\d\ ]*.?\d*([][+-]?\d+)?$ but this does not work. On debugging, the value is read from the textbox as 12-345.00 but, '-' is not exactly a hyphen. I searched online and found some references to '\xa0' which is hexadecimal white space, but i don't find any way to handle this in the regex. Here is the javascript function:

```
function regexTest() {                        
    var exp = new RegExp("^[+-]?[\\d\\ ]*\\.?\\d*([][+-]?\\d+)?$");

    var price = document.getElementById("txtConverted").value;

    if (price.match(exp)) {
        alert("pass");
        return true;
    }
    else {
        alert("fail");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Edit: for additional understanding, i was getting a character like this -

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add `\xao` (non-breaking space) to the character class, i.e. `[\\d\\xao]`.
It is a hexadecimal escape sequence representing the character at decimal unicode code point 160.

Answer (score 1):

you could use this expression below to catch white space or hyphen. but I would suggest you use string.Replace("-", "") to remove the hyphen first.

```
var exp = new RegExp(@"^[+-]?[\d\s|-]*\.?\d*([][+-]?\d+)?$");
```

The @ in front of the string to remove the escape characters.

Comment: actually that character is not hyphen. When i copy it in sql editor, its - in red color. when i changed my regex to catch the hyphen it did not work.

Comment: i've edited the question and added what i got on pasting the content of the textbox value while debugging, into sql editor

Comment: thanx a bunch!! it worked with xa0 :) :)

but i have a concern, in my actual application, i'm creating this regex dynamically; application picks up the format culture based on a config. And the regex is constructed using "NumberGroupSeparator" and "DecimalSeparator" coming from the cultureinfo for that culture.

right now, number separator for this culture is space, for some other culture it might be something else

Any idea how i can incorporate, xa0 in this case? 
(i didn't want to have a conditional logic there :().

Comment: yes.. something like that, but en-ZA culture had problem as it was having separator space, which was not actually "\ " or "\s" but \xa0

Comment: var numberFormatRegex = new RegExp("^[+-]?[\\d\\" + groupSeparator + "]*\\" + decimalSeparator + "?\\d*([][+-]?\\d+)?$");

Comment: If you are getting unexpected character in between your string, then you may want to find a way to remove them before, matching them to specific culture.

Comment: @Jegan: yes, i am doing the same.

String.prototype.removecharacter = function () { return this.replace(/\xa0/, ' '); };